# Creating new column based on condition from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

As my previously written question was quite ambiguous and stupidly written, I will be more explicit in this thread. This is the previous post: [How can I create a new column to SQL while adding conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604542/how-can-i-create-a-new-column-to-sql-while-adding-conditions)

Basically, the two tables are these:

**vw_RecipeIngredientCheck** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlArc.png)

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [RecipeName]
      ,[RecipeIngredientName]
      ,[Unit]
      ,[Amount]
      ,[DisplayOrder]
      ,[IngredientGroup]
      ,[VirtualProductName]
  FROM [dbo].[vw_RecipeIngredientCheck]
```

**VirtualProduct** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU8S7.png)

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
      ,[Name]
      ,[NativeUnitID]
      ,[Mapping]
      ,[Kg]
      ,[g]
      ,[l]
      ,[dl]
      ,[unit]
      ,[empty]
      ,[pack]
      ,[teaspoon]
      ,[spoon]
      ,[can]
      ,[bundle]
      ,[clove]
      ,[smidgen]
      ,[cube]
      ,[stick]
      ,[slice]
      ,[IsDurable]
      ,[letter]
      ,[Glass]
      ,[ProductImageId]
      ,[ResolvesToRealProduct]
  FROM [dbo].[VirtualProduct]
```

My goal is to create a new column in the vw_RecipeIngredientCheck table which converts the Unit to a standard unit (which is given in the VirtualProduct table and is called *NativeUnitID*).

To be noted that the units in the VirtualProduct table already have the logic for converting implemented.

So, the point is to create a new column in vw_RecipeIngredientCheck and using the [VirtualProductName] to then multiply the [Amount] with the column from table VirtualProduct named after its [Unit].

Example:

[NewColumn] = [Amount] * (column name in VirtualProduct = [Unit])

Essentially, after joining the two tables I got this:

[Joined tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXmu5.png)

I don't know how to write the SQL Query so that the *Amount* gets multiplied by the column that matches its *Unit*. For example, in the image above, the row with Index 33 has the following:
NativeUnitID: 3 (which is Kg)
Unit: g
Amount: 250

In the column *IngredientStd* I would like to have the conversion of the current amount in grams into its NativeUnitID, which is Kg. Basically, the amount should be multiplied with the column "g", which is basically the content of the *Unit* column. What is troubling for me is comparing the values inside [Unit] with the name of the columns.

Comment: Is it MySQL DB or it's on SQL server?

Comment: It is SQL server

Comment: I also thought of using Pandas for this task. Do you think it would make my work easier?

Comment: You mean you do not need to make the column data on-the-fly each time for tables, but to calculate and put data in the column? Then surely you can use whatever language you have experience with (i.e. Python with Pandas).

Answer (score 0):

You have to try the dynamic table creation query to achieve this.
Reference: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/creating-a-dynamic-table-in-sql-server1

Comment: Appreciate the hint, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the table listing various weight units to a table with two data columns - name of unit and weight coefficient relative to most common unit (say 1 gramm). Then IMHO you could easily use two joins of tables by unit name, first converting to *standard unit*, then to your *Native Unit*. IMHO there is not much value in maintaining DB logic with names of units as names of columns. Maybe you really need it (or it is very convenient to use) for something else, then my advice is not applicable.

Comment: I will try to do that, although I am afraid I can't really change the tables as the logic behind them is already being used somewhere else.